# Python Script downloading instead of running?

Tags: python, cgi, tomcat6

I am running Python 2.7 in Tomcat 6, which I have done for a while, but for some reason now when I go to my pages the browser attempts to download the file instead of running the script. I can get a simple hello.py to work as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html>Hello World From CGI!</html>"
```

but if I try to add even just an import

```
import MySQLdb
```

then the browser tries to download the file. Any idea what's going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: Does maybe your import fail or something else in your script? What is actually downloaded? What do your logs say?

Comment: It's possible the import fails, I notice on chrome it doesn't actually  download a file, it just shows blank

Comment: that seems to be the problem, if I take out the includes then i get errors, obviously, but it renders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does maybe your import fail or something else in your script? What is
>   actually downloaded? What do your logs say?

Imports were failing